# Android Studio Build Failing - "Parse Error at [row, col]:[33:57]"

Tags: android, xml

im trying to compile my app, but the ide shows an error at ":app:mergeDebugResources", that is "ParseError at [row,col]:[33,47]", i think the error is in my activity_main.xml file, but i cant find it, please help.

Here is the file:-

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/rocketView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                app:strokeWidth="1dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="5dp">
```

the error occurs at the last character of the last line, after '"5dp">(here)'.

Full XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-3dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/rocketView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                app:strokeWidth="1dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="22-05-2021"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="SFS Gaming"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="0.8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0.8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0.8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket1"
                        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket1"
                        android:background="@drawable/imageview_border"
                        android:cropToPadding="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Custom Starship"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/rocketView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:strokeWidth="1dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="22-05-2021"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="SFS Gaming"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket2"
                        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket2"
                        android:background="@drawable/imageview_border"
                        android:cropToPadding="true"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Eagle 1+"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/rocketView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:strokeWidth="1dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="22-05-2021"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="SFS Gaming"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket3"
                        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket3"
                        android:background="@drawable/imageview_border"
                        android:cropToPadding="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Space Station"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/rocketView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:strokeWidth="1dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="22-05-2021"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket4"
                        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/rocket4"
                        android:background="@drawable/imageview_border"
                        android:cropToPadding="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Eagle 9+ 1st Stage"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="SFS Gaming"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `app:cardElevation="5dp"` instead of `card_view:cardElevation="5dp"`

Comment: thanks, solution was a bit different, actually i mentioned app:cardElevation="5dp" before card_view:cardElevation="5dp", so compiler error occured, :)